# Jenkins EnvInject plugin send mail to the build initiator

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

How to have a report being sent automatically to the Jenkins build initiator (via mentioned plug-in) ?

Comment: Jenkins EnvInject plugin is used to manage variables. If you need send some report, just add a build step to do that

Comment: How will it look like, could you give me some examples. And I don't understand what variables should I use for this purpose. Sorry for this simple questions, but I am new in Jenkins

Comment: No worries :). First tell me a resume of your requirement.

Comment: @JRichardsz I have a string parameter called {reportToEmail} with default value=emails. 
Also I did stage - send email if you fill up it with string parameter. See the following

Comment: stage("Report") {
    
        node {
          zip zipFile: 'reports.zip', dir: 'reports'
          emailext attachmentsPattern: 'reports.zip', body: 'Find attachments', subject: 'SoapUIReport', to: '${reportToEmail}'

Comment: When build will be done I need to send email with results to the Jenkins build initiator automatically. I have no idea how will do it

Comment: We can say that your current  jenkins-job  perform the following tasks : (1) receive a parameter with email recipients (2) generate a zip on the server which jenkins is running (3) Just need send an email to recipients attaching your zip file as final step?  Confirm this to answer you. Also if you think, update your question to something like : How send email with zip attachment?

Comment: actually it is slightly different, Jenkins should send email with results to person who have started the build and recipients list(this step I have done)

Comment: (01) User joe , logins in jenkins. (02)Joe click in "build with parameters" option in some jenkins job. (03) Joe fill some parameters like email_recipients and press build button (04) Job starts , generate a report.zip and as a final step you need send an email with report.zip ..... is this correct ? ANother question : reports.zip is a full html report or you just need attach the log of build showing the result ?

Comment: Yes,everything is correct. I need attach the log of build showing the result

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Hi @artez . This plugin : https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin, has a option called : attach build log. So you dont need extra configuration. If this is what you need, change your question and I will show you how use this plugin as an answer.

Comment: Hi @JRichardsz many thanks for your support here ! How I resolve issues: I added emailext attachLog: true, body: 'Find attachments', compressLog: true, recipientProviders: [requestor()], subject: 'blablabla'